# Can't get a simple divide select statement to work in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, select, rounding

I have a the following code

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.First_Name || ' ' || M.Surname AS Manager,
                SUM(CASE WHEN MC.Team = F.Home_Team AND 
                              MC.Start_Date <= F.Date AND 
                              MC.End_Date >= F.Date THEN 1 WHEN MC.Team = F.Away_Team AND 
                                                                MC.Start_Date <= F.Date AND 
                                                                MC.End_Date >= F.Date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Games,
                SUM(CASE WHEN S.HTFT > S.ATFT AND 
                              F.Home_Team = 48 AND 
                              MC.Start_Date <= F.Date AND 
                              MC.End_Date >= F.Date THEN 3 WHEN S.ATFT > S.HTFT AND 
                                                                F.Away_Team = 48 AND 
                                                                MC.Start_Date <= F.Date AND 
                                                                MC.End_Date >= F.Date THEN 3 WHEN S.HTFT = S.ATFT AND 
                                                                                                  MC.Start_Date <= F.Date AND 
                                                                                                  MC.End_Date >= F.Date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Points,
                (SUM(1.0 * CASE WHEN S.HTFT > S.ATFT AND 
                                     F.Home_Team = 48 AND 
                                     MC.Start_Date <= F.Date AND 
                                     MC.End_Date >= F.Date THEN 3 WHEN S.ATFT > S.HTFT AND 
                                                                       F.Away_Team = 48 AND 
                                                                       MC.Start_Date <= F.Date AND 
                                                                       MC.End_Date >= F.Date THEN 3 WHEN S.HTFT = S.ATFT AND 
                                                                                                         MC.Start_Date <= F.Date AND 
                                                                                                         MC.End_Date >= F.Date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / SUM(CASE WHEN MC.Team = F.Home_Team AND 
                                                                                                                                                                  MC.Start_Date <= F.Date AND 
                                                                                                                                                                  MC.End_Date >= F.Date THEN 1 WHEN MC.Team = F.Away_Team AND 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    MC.Start_Date <= F.Date AND 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    MC.End_Date >= F.Date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ) AS PPG
  FROM Manager AS M
       LEFT JOIN
       Manager_Contract AS MC ON M.ID = MC.Manager
       LEFT JOIN
       Fixture AS F ON MC.Team = F.Home_Team OR 
                       MC.Team = F.Away_Team
       LEFT JOIN
       Score AS S ON F.ID = S.Fixture
 GROUP BY M.First_Name || ' ' || M.Surname
HAVING Games > 0
 ORDER BY MC.Start_Date ASC;
```

Which returns

| Manager | Games | Points | PPG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ben Garner | 10 | 12 | 1.2 |
| Paul Tisdale | 15 | 12 | 0.8 |
| Tommy Widdrington | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| Joey Barton | 18 | 11 | 0.61111 |

The last column I want to return

| PPG |
| --- |
| 1.20 |
| 0.80 |
| 1.00 |
| 0.61 |

Every time I try to add ROUND in I get an error message - Usually Row value misused.

Any help appreciated.

I am using SQLite Studio and MacBook Pro.

QUESTION EDITED - Managed to fix initial issue.

Comment: Since you don't use ROUND, how can that be the problem?  The problem is that you are dividing integers, which gives an integer result.

Comment: SQLite performs integer division. Multiply by 1.0 before the division.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message:

> Row value misused

is often the result of incorrect usage of parentheses and this may happen because your code contains many conditions in all the branches of the `CASE` expressions.

I think that you can simplify the code.

The condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING Games > 0
```

will filter out any managers for which this `CASE` expression:

```
CASE 
  WHEN MC.Team = F.Home_Team 
   AND MC.Start_Date <= F.Date 
   AND MC.End_Date >= F.Date THEN 1 
  WHEN MC.Team = F.Away_Team 
   AND MC.Start_Date <= F.Date 
   AND MC.End_Date >= F.Date THEN 1 
  ELSE 0 
END
```

is always `0`.

So, why don't you set a `WHERE` clause, equivalent to the above conditions?
Also, this makes the first 2 `LEFT` joins actually `INNER` joins (and I'm not sure if the last join should be a `LEFT` join).

Try this simplified code:

```
SELECT M.First_Name || ' ' || M.Surname AS Manager,
       COUNT(*) AS Games,
       SUM(
         CASE 
           WHEN (S.HTFT > S.ATFT AND F.Home_Team = 48) OR (S.ATFT > S.HTFT AND F.Away_Team = 48) THEN 3 
           WHEN S.HTFT = S.ATFT THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 
         END
       ) AS Points,
       ROUND(
         1.0 *
         SUM(
           CASE 
             WHEN (S.HTFT > S.ATFT AND F.Home_Team = 48) OR (S.ATFT > S.HTFT AND F.Away_Team = 48) THEN 3 
             WHEN S.HTFT = S.ATFT THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END
         ) / 
         COUNT(*)
         , 2
       ) AS PPG
FROM Manager AS M
INNER JOIN manager_Contract AS MC ON M.ID = MC.Manager
INNER JOIN Fixture AS F ON MC.Team IN (F.Home_Team, F.Away_Team)
LEFT JOIN Score AS S ON F.ID = S.Fixture
WHERE MC.Start_Date <= F.Date AND MC.End_Date >= F.Date
GROUP BY Manager;
```